# Apply security to this Document Library" is not getting displayed

Tags: sharepoint-server

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18415/Custom-Activity-Workflow-for-implementing-Item-Lev

I have followed all the steps accordingly as given in the article (the link pasted above). The problem is when I select the Item Level Security activity in SharePoint designer 2007 and then click Add, it is not getting added up.

I mean to say, "Apply security to this Document Library" is not getting displayed!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your link is not in the post!